# Can it be considered a pure function?

Tags: scala, referential-transparency

I'm currently designing a functional application and stuck with a concept of referential transparency. I have the following trait

```
trait RemoteStringStorage[F[_]]{
    def getAndDeleteOnSuccess(f: String => F[Unit]): F[Unit]
}
```

What the `getAndDeleteOnSuccess` is supposed to do is to extract a `String` from some remote storage and apply `f: String => F[Unit]` (which is pure) to it. In case of success the `String` should be deleted from the storage. I cannot split the method to multiple methods since I use Storage-specific API that can perform such operation atomically.

The question is if such function is pure. Or is there any reason to define the trait as

```
trait RemoteStringStorage[F[_]]{
    def getAndDeleteOnSuccess(f: F[String => F[Unit]]): F[Unit]
}
```

?

Comment: That would really depend on `F`. For example, if `F` is `Id` (the type of effect that has no effect) and your program is running IO operations to delete values from storage, then no. But, if `F` is `IO`, then we can still purely reason about the IO effect as the value *describing* the deletion of a file from storage, when ran, and that still follows the rules of a pure function. Although we can endlessly debate if IO is pure or not :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Sounds reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: The basic idea of *referential transparency* is that you can replace an expression with the result of its evaluation or vice versa without changing the meaning of the program. E.g. in C, `printf` returns the number of characters written, but you cannot replace `printf("Hello")` with `6` without changing the meaning of the program, therefore, `printf` is not pure. I find that the stupid process of simply going through the exercise of replacing calls to (in this case) `getAndDeleteOnSuccess` with its return value and seeing if that changes something is very enlightening.